# How to compare characters in a string in C language

Tags: c, string, char

```
   char name[]="Rajas";
    char ch;
    ch=name[0];

   if(ch=="R")
   printf("Found");


   return 0;
```

Why is this not working?
I want to separate vowels and consonants from a string, by comparing their characters.
I was able to do this in C++ language by

```
int i=0;
char name[]="String";
string ch[20];
while(name[i]!='\0')
{
  ch[i]=name[i];
  i++;
}
```

Comment: The code you showed has neither sense. It has nothing common with what you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this not working?

The problem is here:

```
if(ch=="R")
printf("Found");
```

Notice that `"R"` is a string literal. `'R'` is a constant character. The latter is what you need here as you cannot compare a string literal with a single character.

The code should be instead:

```
char name[] = "Rajas";
char ch = name[0];

if(ch == 'R') {
printf("R is found");
}
```

By the way you can omit the `char` object `ch`:

```
char name[] = "Rajas";

if(name[0] == 'R') {
printf("R is found");
}
```

---

Also as a side-note: The code you showed at the second example is in its purpose completely different than the first one as you coping characters of a string inside an array of `char` in the second example, while in the first example you only looking for a matching character in the first element of an array of `char`.

Comment: @RajasPaunikar I´m glad, that I could help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`"R"` is a string literal of type `char[2]` - containing `'R'` and `'\0'`. That's not what you want to compare with.

You need to compare with *char* `'R'`:

```
  if(ch == 'R')
      printf("Found");
```